# Error: null, while compiling resource bundles under Linux with hudson

Tags: linux, apache-flex, ant, hudson

I am using Flex 3.5.0.12683 with hudson CI server and Ant to compile our project. While compiling resource bundles for this project I am having problems.

With root user everything is compiled successfully but when I am trying to compile my flex project with hudson (ant) it fails with:

```
compile_resource:
[mxmlc] Loading configuration file /opt/lib/flex3.5/frameworks/flex-config.xml
[mxmlc] Error: null
[mxmlc]
[mxmlc] java.lang.NullPointerException
[mxmlc]     at flex2.tools.CommandLineConfiguration.compilingResourceModule(CommandLineConfiguration.java:70)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.tools.CommandLineConfiguration.getTargetFile(CommandLineConfiguration.java:45)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.tools.CommandLineConfiguration.validate(CommandLineConfiguration.java:97)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.tools.Compiler.processConfiguration(Compiler.java:672)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.tools.Compiler.processConfiguration(Compiler.java:526)
[mxmlc]     at flex2.tools.Compiler.mxmlc(Compiler.java:84)
[mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[mxmlc]     at flex.ant.FlexTask.executeInProcess(FlexTask.java:283)
[mxmlc]     at flex.ant.FlexTask.execute(FlexTask.java:225)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[mxmlc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[mxmlc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1360)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1329)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1212)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
[mxmlc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Looks like there some permissions fails but I can't figure what and where since there is no much output from compiler.

Comment: well just looked into CommandLineConfiguration.java file and found failing line:
resourceModulePath = I18nUtils.getGeneratedResourceModule(this).getPath();
seems that compiler can't find where resources stored under simple user

Comment: So I'm guessing whatever user hudson is running in, it doesn't have some permissions to access the needed paths.

Comment: Yes, seems so. Currently solved this problem by adding hudson to sudoers file with permissions to run mxmlc and compc. But, sure it's not real solution.

Comment: Is there a way on Debian to detect which paths mxmlc tries to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the compiler create a directory /tmp/Adobe/Flex/GeneratedResourceModules and create a temporary file under the directory while compiling a resource module, if super user compiled at first on the system other normal users can't create the temporary file. To avoid this I executed the following commands before normal user compile.

> chmod a+w /tmp/Adobe/Flex/GeneratedResourceModules

or

> rm -rf /tmp/Adobe

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have super-user privs on the box, you could also change where the compiler is placing the output file by setting the **java.io.tmpdir** property in the mxmlc ant task:

```
<java jar="${FLEX_HOME}/lib/mxmlc.jar" failonerror="true" fork="true">
  <jvmarg value="-Djava.io.tmpdir=${MY_OUTPUT_DIR}"/>
  ...
```